# JQuery: Check if element will trigger by default

Tags: jquery, triggers

I'm working on extending JQuery's .val() to prevent the need to add a .trigger('change') at the end, but only if the element won't be triggered to begin with such as with a hidden input.  Is there a way to check this?

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you check the element type before firing the event

Comment: Well I'm hoping for something a bit more broad rather than adjusting for a specific situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: Extend .val to include .trigger()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417802/jquery-extend-val-to-include-trigger)