# JQuery: Extend .val() to include .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just did a quick google on how to extend functions in JQuery and, well, I have no clue what I'm doing.  I want to understand in general, but in this specific instance I want to extend the .val() function to add a trigger 'change' event to everything, because certain elements like hidden inputs do not do so by default.  So in other words, this:

```
$('#element').val('newval');
```

Would automatically be turned into this:

```
$('#element').val('newval').trigger('change');
```

Here's my attempt...it's breaking my page, but hopefully I'm close:

```
        (function($, input){

            var oldValFn = $.fn.val;

            $.fn.val = function() {
                var ret = oldValFn.apply(this, arguments);
                try {
                                            $(this).val(input);
                    $(this).trigger('change');
                }
                catch(e) 
                {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                return ret;
            }

            $(this).val('newval');

            })(jQuery);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as this is obviously something that I need to understand conceptually.  Thanks!

Comment: there is not need to set `$(this).val(input)`.... other than that it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RA88u/1/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that's not the best solution and it has some drawbacks (lots of overhead since `$.fn.val` already calls `this.val` internally as well) but this implementation seems to be working fine and avoids infinite loops by not triggering the change event if the value haven't changed.

*Note that it haven't been fully tested but if you are serious about this plugin, you could write some test cases.*

```
!function ($, oldValFn) {
    $.fn.val = function () {
        var args = arguments;

        if (!args.length) return oldValFn.call(this);

        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                oldVal = oldValFn.call($this),
                result = oldValFn.apply($this, args),
                newVal = oldValFn.call($this);

            if (args.length && oldVal !== newVal) {
                $this.trigger('change');
            }
        });

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery, jQuery.fn.val);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RA88u/13/)

Comment: You'd really need to introduce a loop. When you do `oldValFn.call(this)`, you're getting only the first element's value, even if there's more than one.

Comment: @user2736012 Yes, I forgot about that case. Fixed.